# How to solve ODE $(h')^2+(h^2)' f=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve the ode $(h')^2+(h^2)'f=1$ when we know $f(x)$ and initial value of $h(x)$?

Comment: What is $f$ ? Is $h=h(f)$ ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici f is $f(x)$

Comment: Do you want to solve it for any $f(x)$ or are you solving it for a specific $f(x)$?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by the "initial value of $h(x)h'(x)$. Do you mean initial values of $h(x)$ and $h'(x)$, and if so, how does the initial value of $h'(x)$ make sense in the context of the first order ODE that you have?

Comment: If you make the substitution $y(x)=h'(x)$, then you have the implicit integral equation $y^2(x)+2y(x)f(x)\int_0^\xi y(\xi)\mathrm d\xi=1$. While I can't rule it out, I don't see an obvious closed form solution.

Comment: You could of course solve the quadratic in $h'(x)$, but except for the trivial case of $f(x)=1$, you can't reduce the ODE to separable form.

Comment: @Eli I want to solve it for any $f$. And if there is some $f(x)$ special that can be solved, thank you very much.

Comment: @Sharat V Chandrasekhar  Thank you very much. How to solve the quadratic in $h'$?

Comment: Just substitute $y=h’$ and you have a quadratic in $y$ noting that $(h^2)’=2hh’=2hy$. Then jus use the quadratic formula.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Thank you! But the result is about $h$, and not easy to get the final solution.

Comment: Well, to get $h(x)$, you would have to integrate $h’(x)$. This would most likely have to be done numerically. Are you familiar with Runge-Kutta methods?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is good enough for you, but we can get a power series solution and a recurrence relation for computing coefficients (see the last section if TL;DR).

Let $$h(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$$ be a power series solution for $h$.

Firstly, since we know $f$ completely, we can expand it into its Taylor series $$f(x) = \sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$$

Next, note $(h')^2 + (h^2)' f = (h')^2 + 2 h h' f = 1$. Put $x = 0$, we get $(h'(0))^2 + 2 h(0) h'(0) f(0) = 1$, which implies $h'(0) = - h(0) f(0) \pm \sqrt{h(0)^2 f(0)^2 - 1}$. Notice $a_0 = h(0)$ and $a_1 = h'(0)$, so we now know $a_0$ and $a_1$.

---

Observe
$$h' = \sum_n n a_n x^{n - 1} = \sum_n (n + 1) a_{n + 1} x^n$$
and hence
$$\begin{align}
(h')^2
&= \sum_n \left[\sum_0^n (k + 1) (n - k + 1) a_{k + 1} a_{n - k + 1} \right] x^n \\
&= \sum_n \left[\sum_0^n (k + 1) (n + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{n + 1 - k} \right] x^n
\end{align}$$
using the product formula.

Similarly,
$$\begin{align}
h^2
&= \sum_n \left(\sum_0^n a_k a_{n - k}\right) x^n \\
(h^2)'
&= \sum_n \left(n \sum_0^n a_k a_{n - k}\right) x^{n - 1} \\
&= \sum_n \left((n + 1) \sum_0^{n + 1} a_k a_{n + 1 - k}\right) x^n
\end{align}$$
and hence
$$(h^2)' f = \sum_n \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] x^n$$
Summing the 2 terms gives
$$(h^2)' + (h^2)' f \\
= \sum_n \left\{\left[\sum_0^n (k + 1) (n + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{n + 1 - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right]\right\} x^n \\
= 1$$
Now the constant term
$$\left[\sum_0^0 (k + 1) (0 + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{0 + 1 - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^0 \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(0 - k)}(0)}{(0 - k)!}\right] \\
= a_{1}^2+ \left[\left(\sum_0^{1} a_j a_{1 - j}\right) f(0)\right] \\
= a_{1}^2 + 2 a_0 a_1 f(0) \\
= 1$$
Recall $a_0 = h(0)$ and $a_1 = h'(0)$. Hence the above condition is exactly the same as the one we've encountered earlier.

For non-constant term, for each $n \ge 1$,
$$\left[\sum_0^n (k + 1) (n + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{n + 1 - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] = 0$$

This looks like a horrible mess. But actually, it defines a recurrence relation that can help us compute $a_{n + 1}$ from $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n$.

To see it, notice we can isolate all terms with $a_{n + 1}$ on the LHS
$$\left[\sum_0^n (k + 1) (n + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{n + 1 - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_1 a_{n + 1} + \left[\sum_1^{n - 1} (k + 1) (n + 1 - k) a_{k + 1} a_{n + 1 - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_1 a_{n + 1} + \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^n \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_1 a_{n + 1} + \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[(n + 1) f(0) \sum_0^{n + 1} a_j a_{n + 1 - j}\right] + \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_1 a_{n + 1} + \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[(n + 1) f(0) \left(2 a_0 a_{n + 1} + \sum_1^n a_j a_{n + 1 - j}\right)\right] + \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_1 a_{n + 1} + 2 (n + 1) f(0) a_0 a_{n + 1} + \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[(n + 1) f(0) \sum_0^{n - 1} a_{j + 1} a_{n - j}\right] + \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 2 (n + 1) a_{n + 1} (a_1  + f(0) a_0) + \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[(n + 1) f(0) \sum_0^{n - 1} a_{k + 1} a_{n - k}\right] + \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right] \\
= 0$$

and hence
$$a_{n + 1} = - \frac{f(0)}{2 (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} a_{k + 1} a_{n - k}\right] \\
- \frac{1}{2 (n + 1) (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] \\
- \frac{1}{2 (n + 1) (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right]$$

---

To sum up, given $h(0)$ and $f(x)$. The solution to $(h')^2 + (h^2)' f = 1$ is
$$h(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$$
where $a_0 = h(0), a_1 = - h(0) f(0) \pm \sqrt{h(0)^2 f(0)^2 - 1}$
and
$$a_{n + 1} = - \frac{f(0)}{2 (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} a_{k + 1} a_{n - k}\right] \\
- \frac{1}{2 (n + 1) (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 2} (k + 2) (n - k) a_{k + 2} a_{n - k}\right] \\
- \frac{1}{2 (n + 1) (a_1  + f(0) a_0)} \left[\sum_0^{n - 1} \left((k + 1) \sum_0^{k + 1} a_j a_{k + 1 - j}\right) \frac{f^{(n - k)}(0)}{(n - k)!}\right]$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I need for a closed form solution, thank you for your answer very much!

Comment: @HappySuperman I've updated the ans to reflect the latest change of initial condiiton in your question. I've also figured out an explicit recurrence relation for $a_{n + 1}$, which makes the solution slightly more explicit. But I highly doubt there is a closed form solution in term of elementary functions. Power series / numerical solution may be the best we can do.